# Beginners threading in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, iis

Can you recommend a good series of articles *or preferably a book* on how to get started with threading in general and in C# in particular?
I am primarily looking for the use of threads in console applications and in ASP.Net apps.

I understand only the very basics of threads and know that "here be dragons", so want to get a good grounding in it before I start using them.

Things I am curious about are things like the concept of having a threadpool, how you manage the size of it, how you choose for things to be queued until a thread is available vs forcing a new thread to start etc.
Also, I understand that IIS has lots of built-in thread handling, so anything that explains how to work with threads in ASP.Net under IIS and how it differs from threading in a console C# applicaion is interesting.

My intended usage includes things like;

- The user does something on the ASP.Net page that causes my server-side code to need to connect to another system and carry out lengthy operations, so I want to return control to the user quickly by firing that action to another thread. The user can keep watching progress through AJAX or simply move away - the web is stateless after all :)
- Use of Fire and Forget patterns (lots of sample code out there, I want to understand more about how they work)

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As well as my own articles linked by Andrew, Joe Albahari has [another tutorial](http://albahari.com/threading).

If you want a really thorough examination, read Joe Duffy's [Concurrent Programming in Windows](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032143482X).

Comment: I just posted the same answer and have now deleted it to upvote yours instead, because you beat me to it.

Comment: I'm working through Duffy's book as I have time.  So far its excellent and I like his no-nonsense writing style.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a good set of articles by our very own Jon Skeet:

http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/

Comment: This is what I use for all C# threading questions I have.

Comment: You should be aware that it was written before .NET 2.0 came out though, which is why there's nothing about BackgroundWorker (IIRC). I really ought to update it some time.

Comment: +1 Jon T: Me too, just happened two days ago while transfer bulk of data from gridview to excel sheet, and because skeet's article i do it async in a five minutes. thanks Jon.

Answer (score 4):

I found this [free ebook](http://www.albahari.com/threading/) by Joseph Albahari really useful

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend the series by Joseph Albahari available here:

http://www.albahari.com/threading/

It's concise and very readable.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend the following

[Great MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163744.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Get "[CLR Via C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735621632)" by Jeff Richter.  Its the best .Net book I have ever read and has extensive information on threading.

[image]