# Best practice of writing a program which has too many data collection processes C#

Tags: c#, authentication, data-collection

I have to login in to various elements to retrieve some data, problem is each element has its own login credentials, I want to write all such data collection processes into one single program so that I dont have 10 different scheduled processes to look at.

Did any of you have such a challenge, if so how did you go about it? I am right now doing it the top down way, so its after the first data collection process gets implemented the program goes for the next...

I know that this is not the right way, I have threads and processes in mind, but being a beginner I'm kinda lost now.

Comment: "Top down" is probably not the right term. "Sequential" or "procedural" would be more fitting given that description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the process of collecting data of the different sources is taking longer you could get faster results if you do it with multithreading and callbacks, but if in normal case it takes not really long, why not make it as simple as possible.

Comment: Can you show me a good example giving a demo of multithreading

Comment: sure, just use stackoverflows search, you will find the informations. for the beginning i would just jumpstart here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/533042/beginners-threading-in-c

and there you find links to tutorials. but as already mentioned, if not really necessary i wouldn't do it!

Answer (score 0):

Its going to depend on how you need to login to each element, and what it means to "collect" the data. If you can give some specific types of elements (SQL, Oracle, AS/400, etc) and what you are trying to get out of them, then we can help you get started with automating the process.