# C# Threading: Exercises for beginners

Tags: c#, multithreading

So far I have been trying to master threading by immediately implementing threads in my project. And I have been trying to do that for a long time. But this hasn't resulted any results, nor gave me any experience with threading. The only thing that the attempting gave me is the impression that threading in C# has many important refinements.

I couldn't find any simple exercises about threading. I'm searching for exercises where you have to make different simple console applications. I am searching for simple exercises so I can get an idea of how things work when working with threads and master that idea. I have seen a book of programming exercises with difficulty that gets harder as the problem's number gets bigger. I am searching for something similar. Afterwards I will continue with more complicated stuff and try to add threads in my project (which is made with Windows Forms).

Where can I find exercises/book of exercises about threading in C#?

EDIT:

I am NOT looking for any tutorials- I can find them myself. I am searching for exercises and exercises only. If there are no such exercises, please, tell me.

Comment: Check out book Visual C# 2012 it does cover loads about threading and task factory

Comment: One thing that's hard to realize is that threading doesn't improve the performance of most applications. Be certain that you need it before you use it.

Comment: I'm certain that I need it.

Comment: possible duplicate:  [Beginners threading in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/533042/beginners-threading-in-c-sharp?rq=1)

Comment: I am NOT searching for any tutorials- I am searching for exercises.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple exercises:

1) change code that works (learn by example)

- open any tutorial
- find code samples
- play with code samples, see what works and what does not

2) answer questions on SO (learn by teaching)

- find an interesting question
- answer it (you should do a research to do this)
- talk and interact with other users

Answer (score 4):

Joseph Albahari has a great article called [Threading in C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/). This is really cool blog post about start to learn for threading in C#. Joseph clearly explained:

- Introduction and Concepts
- Join and Sleep
- How Threading Works
- Creating and Starting Threads
- Thread Pooling

And check [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1137/Threading-in-C) out article from Codeproject.

- Getting Started

You can create and start a new thread by instantiating a `Thread` object and calling
its Start method. The simplest constructor for Thread takes a `ThreadStart` delegate:
a parameterless method indicating where execution should begin.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

class ThreadTest
{
   static void Main()
   {
      Thread t = new Thread (WriteY); // Kick off a new thread
      t.Start(); // running WriteY()
      // Simultaneously, do something on the main thread.
      for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) Console.Write ("x");
   }
   static void WriteY()
   {
      for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) Console.Write ("y");
      }
}

// Output:
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxyyyyyyyyyyyyy
yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
yyyyyyyyyyyyyxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
...
```

If you want to learn threading deeply get a copy of [C# 4.0 in a Nutshell](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/)

Comment: The tutorial about the two progress bars is nice. But your answer is still not answering my question.

Answer (score -1):

Threading is pretty straight forward.  Here is a popular link regarding it:  http://www.albahari.com/threading/

Basics:

Create a method that returns void and takes no arguments.  Like this:

```
private void MyThreadMethod()
{
    //Some code here.
}
```

To call that method in a thread simply do this in a button on a form.

```
var thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(MyThreadMethod));
thread.Start();
```

That will create a thread and start it off and run the code in the `MyThreadMethod`.

Now, the devil is in the details.  Thread safety and management of threads is where the real art of threading and multitasking is.  Another thing to consider is Threads vs Tasks which are much more user-friendly.

Comment: And that's why I need exercises: in order to master the knowledge- I can't implement it immediately in my project.

Comment: Visit the link at the top of my post.  It has a few levels of tutorials.  I really think it will give you what you need.

Comment: I need exercises, not tutorials, with which I can turn the knowledge into skill.